# Jquery Search for a string

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-ui

I have an input textbox  for users to search for another user by either first name, Last Name or full name and if name found, either hide the non-match one or color the found one.
My  structure looks

```js
const userSerach = ($("#userId").val() || '').toLowerCase();

const usersInRow = $(this).find('td').eq(6);
const users = usersInRow[0].innerText;
const userFound = users.substring(users.contains(userSerach)).toLowerCase();
if (userFound.length > 0) {
  $(userFound).css('color', 'red');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="userId" placeholder="Search by user's name" value="">
<dl>
  <dt>ADMINISTRATORs (<span style="color: red;">3</span>)</dt>
  <dd>Louis,Edward</dd>
  <dd>Gary,Anthony</dd>
  <dd>Carlson,Matthew</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understood looking at your code is that you want to search matching text into `<dd>` and want to highlight them.

You can do it like below:

```js
$('#userId').keyup(function() {
  userSerach = ($("#userId").val() || '').toLowerCase();
  if (userSerach != '') {
    $('dl dd').each(function() {
      if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(userSerach) > -1) {
        $(this).css('color', 'red');
      } else {
        $(this).css('color', 'black');
      }
    });
  } else {
    $('dd').css('color', 'black');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="userId" placeholder="Search by user's name" value="">
<dl>
  <dt>ADMINISTRATORs</dt>
  <dd>Louis,Edward</dd>
  <dd>Gary,Anthony</dd>
  <dd>Carlson,Matthew</dd>
</dl>
```